# Command 'code' is not available in 'snap/bin/code'

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, xfce

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using xfce desktop environment. I was using [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) vscode docs to install vscode in ubuntu. I ran this command:

```
sudo snap install --classic code # or code-insiders
```

which executed successfully. The documentation does not say how to open VSCODE. I am assuming there is no way to open it using GUI as VS Code did not appear when I tried to search for it using the search application feature?

I searched on stack overflow and found that I should be able to run vs code at this point by running 
`code` in the terminal.

But when I do so I get:

> Command 'code' is available in '/snap/bin/code' The command could not
>   be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment
>   variable. code: command not found

`echo $PATH` gives me:

```
/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

I tried to browse to snap/bin folder and open terminal there but the terminal does not open.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`) file in your home directory (for example, /home/your-user-name/.bashrc) in a text editor.
2. Add `export PATH="/snap/bin:$PATH"` to the last line of the file.
3. Save the `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` file.
4. Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove old symlink and create a new

`rm -f /usr/bin/code` 
`sudo ln -s /usr/share/code/bin/code /usr/bin/code`